# How to make a Racket macro take an integer argument?

Tags: syntax, macros, racket

I've been trying to make a macro for 'wrapping' functions, i.e. if I have a function that will take a list and cons the symbol 'a to the first element, it'd normally be defined as lambda (l) (cons 'a l), but I want a macro that will take a function and a list of integer-expression pairs and 'wrap' that function by making a new function that takes the some arguments of the old function and gets the rest based on the pairs, using the integer as a position and the expression as the value to give the function. Something like this:

```
(wrap list (0 'blah) (2 'bloo) (4 'blee))
```

Should expand to:

```
(lambda (a1 a2 . rest)
  (apply list 'blah a1 'bloo a2 'blee rest))
```

Problem is, I don't know how to get the macro to find the value of the integer in the pair, it only knows it as a syntax object. I'm fairly new to macros and this should be fairly simple, I'm just having trouble with the docs, and I can't find any info on the web other than simple tutorials on macros. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a crazy macro to want to write, especially when [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) is so much more intuitive to use. Instead of `(wrap list (0 'blah) (2 'bloo) (4 'blee))`, you can just use:

```
(cut list 'blah <> 'bloo <> 'blee <...>)
```

That is surely much easier to read.

---

If you *really* must write such a macro, here's one way to go about it, by transforming usages of `wrap` into equivalent usages of `cut`:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse) srfi/26)
(define-syntax (wrap stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    ((_ func:expr (idx:nat expr:expr) ...)
     (let* ((alist (map cons
                        (syntax->datum #'(idx ...))
                        (syntax-e #'(expr ...))))
            (upper (add1 (apply max -1 (map car alist))))
            (listfunc (lambda (i)
                        (cond ((assv i alist) => cdr)
                              (else #'<>)))))
       (with-syntax (((args ...) (build-list upper listfunc)))
         #'(cut func args ... <...>))))))
```

The key to answering your question, about how to get the integers given the syntax objects, is by using [`syntax->datum`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-~3edatum%29%29) (for deep syntax-stripping) or [`syntax-e`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-e%29%29) (for shallow syntax-stripping).

---

(P.S. (To Racket experts reading this.) I'm very new to `syntax-parse`, so I'm sure `syntax-parse` experts can find better ways to write the above. I originally wrote the macro as a `syntax-case` macro, then slapped on `syntax-parse` syntax classes. That's it.)

Comment: That's FANTASTIC. I'd never seen that function before. Thanks a bunch. And I'll have to work on getting comfortable with syntax->datum.